# Is writing conditions inside razor deprecated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

From controller, I'm returning a value using ViewBag to razor page. Based on the value of  ViewBag, I have displayed some partial views like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.CourseName == "Physics")
{
    <partial name="_ExpPhysicsPartial"/>
}

@if (ViewBag.CourseName == "Chemistry")
{
    <partial name="_ExpChemistryPartial"/>
}
```

Is this a kind of deprecated technique somehow in terms of **security purpose**?

Comment: i always try and make the `View` as dumb as possible.  Let the `Controller` build an appropriate model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not deprecated as such, but also not preferred. Its always better to populate a data model and pass that to the view. There are a few advantages of that, one important one being catching compile time vs run time issues with a data model passed as opposed to ViewBag being directly used in a view since its dynamic. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262034/mvc-viewbag-best-practice) post explains more. Hope that helps.